# Facebook&Google ads for multiple websites

Tags: facebook, ads

Please help me with some advice. Until now, I have been created Facebook&Google Ads for many different websites. ( Using different pixels ) 
Now, I have to create ads for multiple websites with different domains, but with the same back-end.
Could you advice me how to use the same Facebook Pixel Code and the same Google account ( for Google Ads and Google analytics ) for these multiple websites with the same back-end? ( I`m not pretty good with coding, I have always used Wordpress plugins for installing Facebook Pixel until now )
I don`t want to tangle my audiences ( between .com and .bg for example ) for my re-targeting campaigns.
Please tell me is there any other option so I can use different Pixels installed separately on the websites.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this question correctly, you want to use the same pixel and audience source for multiple websites? This isn't difficult to do as you'd just install the same pixel code across all the websites like you have already done through Wordpress plugins. That being said, you should look to use a tag manager like Google Tag Manager, which you can use to manage the same pixel(s) but easily manage how they are fired and when.

https://marketingplatform.google.com/about/tag-manager/